# Using Admob sdk 22.4.0 or higher will cause issues to users who use android api level below 33?

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to integrate Admob to my android app.
In the Admob SDK [release notes](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rel-notes), it requires a minimum compileSdkVersion of 33 for sdk v22.4.0 or higher.

So if I integrate Admob sdk v22.4.0 or higher, will cause issues to users who use android api level below 33?

I've tested with a android device with api level 28 but it works fine.
But I want to double-check to be certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not affect your older version device user.

> It requires a minimum compileSdkVersion of 33 for sdk v22.4.0 or higher.

means that they start targeting SDK 33 from this version.
It support your apps SDK 33 version device users.